# Issue Passing parameters from erb template to controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, methods, ruby-on-rails-5, parameter-passing

I am trying to call a method in view template from its respective controller which is acting weirdly based on different conditions.

> PLease note I have tried this after getting failure on this
>   [Triply nested model's form in rails showing error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527439/triply-nested-models-form-in-rails-showing-error)

**First of all the controller method is defined as ->**

```
  helper_method :find_feature

  def find_feature(fid)
    @project.features.find(fid)
  end
```

**And the view file code where this method is called ->**

```
<% @project.features.each do |fet| %>
  <%= "#{fet.name} #{fet.id} " %>  #It does work!!

  <%= render partial: "taskform",locals: { fetr: find_feature(fet.id) } %>
<% end %>
```

## This throws error as `Couldn't find Feature without an ID`

**in the screenshot islt is shown params[:id] is used that is not right sorry for that I have used the method which is written above as find_feature(fid) very sorry I will update the screenshot once I get to my mqchine**

**

> the error shows Couldn't find a feature without an id when called by find_feature(fet.id)

**

BUt when I explicitly test with an id, manually, like->

`<%= render partial: "taskform", locals: { fetr: find_feature(7) } %>`

## This works !

Full stack trace-

```
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:433:in `find_with_ids'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:69:in `find'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:100:in `find'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:140:in `find'
app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:7:in `find_feature'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/helpers.rb:67:in `find_feature'
app/views/projects/show.html.erb:66:in `block in _app_views_projects_show_html_erb__3383934460746758134_70317115637280'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:71:in `each'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:71:in `each'
app/views/projects/show.html.erb:56:in `_app_views_projects_show_html_erb__3383934460746758134_70317115637280'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:159:in `block in render'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:354:in `instrument_render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/template.rb:157:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:44:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:43:in `instrument'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:16:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:44:in `render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:25:in `render'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:219:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:84:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:142:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `block in ms'
/home/ayan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:14:in `ms'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:46:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:31:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:45:in `render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:35:in `default_render'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `block in send_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `tap'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:6:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:194:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:42:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:132:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:41:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:22:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:34:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:256:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:134:in `process'
actionview (5.2.3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:32:in `process'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:191:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:252:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:34:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:52:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `each'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:35:in `serve'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:840:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:192:in `call!'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:169:in `call'
omniauth (1.9.0) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:64:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/tempfile_reaper.rb:15:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/http/content_security_policy.rb:18:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:232:in `context'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:226:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:670:in `call'
activerecord (5.2.3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:559:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:98:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:61:in `call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:30:in `block in call'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `catch'
web-console (3.7.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.1) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.2.3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (5.2.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
rack (2.0.7) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.2.3) lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:660:in `handle_request'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:474:in `process_client'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
puma (3.12.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
Request
Parameters:

{"id"=>"4"}
```

Can anyone suggests what is the reason of this behaviour ?

Comment: What are the params you receive when you do `find_feature(fet.id)`? May I ask, what's supposed `find_feature` to do, if you're looking for the same object in the database where you take the id from?

Comment: PLease refer to the screenshot I attached  for your question -**What are the params you receive when you do find_feature(fet.id)**   it seems it doesn't receive any at all which is surprising as `find_feature(7)` sends the param successfully

Comment: There are no params there.

Comment: Params never come empty unless you edit them explicitly. Add the full stacktrace from some log, no photos.

Comment: **May I ask, what's supposed find_feature to do** - it simply returns a feature by finding by its ID AND NOtable is that I am not doing this from FeaturesController, there is nesting and I am calling it from its parent controller

Comment: added the full stack tace

Comment: Try replacing `@project.features.find(params[:fid])` with `@project.features.find(params[:id])`, note `fid` -> `id`.

Comment: Your params are {"id"=>"4"} and you are using params[:fid] for finding a feature, however, you are saying that your code works when you use explicit id like find_feature(7). Can you also add logs what happens when you pass find_feature(7)?

Comment: ok sure, bu where do i find those logs while passing 7? @KrupaSuthar

Comment: Also, your question is misleading because in your question you are finding feature with @project.features.find(fid) and in error screenshot, you are finding feature with @project.features.find(params[:fid]). Can you please add the controller here where you have defined find_feature method?

Comment: @Achy97 You can find logs in the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `find_feature` with this code `find_feature(fet.id)`, so you want to pass the id as a parameter.

Define the helper_method this way then:

```
def find_feature(fid)
  @project.features.find(fid)
end
```

`params[:fid]` will look for a request parameter with the key `fid` in the request's params hash, you are passing a specific value to the method when you call it.

EDIT: Anyway, I'm not sure why are you doing that, you already have the feature object on the `fet` variable inside the loop, just do this:

```
<%= render partial: "taskform",locals: { fetr: fet } %>
```

Comment: I am extremely sorry for that I had posted some updated code ,  FIRSTLY i TRIED THAT , PLEASE SEE THE EDITED QUESTION, actually after some comments i changed to different things but nothing worked

Comment: surely, I tried that at first , but that is not working <%= render partial: "taskform",locals: { fetr: fet } %>

Comment: actually it is a triply nested form and its the 3rd level form

Comment: You didn't add the `(fid)` argument on the model's definitiion `find_feature(fid)` but I don't think you even need to call that method.

Comment: `but that is not working <%= render partial: "taskform",locals: { fetr: fet } %>` how does that is "not working"? I bet it's a different error, please be more precise, "not working" is too ambiguous.

Comment: yes dont know for which reason its working when I am calling <%= render partial: "taskform", locals: { fetr: find_feature(7) } %>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527439/triply-nested-models-form-in-rails-showing-error

Answer (score 0):

error shows method calling with parmas[:fid], but you defined method as find_feature(fid) for finding feature , so there must be other method which is overriding , try it by giving different name like find_project_features it will work

Comment: if this would be the problem then why did it work when I gave an id as parameter exlicitly  `<%= render partial: "taskform", locals: { fetr: find_feature(7) } %>` @Ashok

Comment: app/controllers/projects_controller.rb:7 this is where from your method is calling, is it same method you defined as helper_method ?

Comment: one more thing when you already  have 'fetr' object in loop, whey don't you pass directly , why are you finding it and firing extra query ?

Comment: if its your requirement then fine other wise you should can write short code like <%= render partial: 'taskform', collection: @project.features, as: :fetr %>, this way you won't need to loop object